# Simulator won't work

Tags: ios, cordova, browser, simulator

Cordova plugins:

```
com.jamiestarke.webviewdebug 1.0.8 "WebView Debug"
cordova-plugin-calendar 4.6.0 "Calendar"
cordova-plugin-camera 3.0.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-console 1.1.0 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.7 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.4 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 5.0.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.0 "File Transfer"
phonegap-plugin-push 1.10.5 "PushPlugin"
```

But I got this error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'pushNotification.register')

I run a Cordova app on IPhone X simulator.
I also got that platform version:
ios 4.5.0

Am I missing something? Why my application wont work correctly?

Cordova serve works perfectly,
but when I run it on simulator, nothing works :(

What I am doing wrong?